# How can I limit the number of rows to show at a time for my gallery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a gallery that is generated from a directory with php.

I'd like to show only 2 rows of 4 images each, so a total of 8 images. There would be a "show more" button at the bottom.

When the user would click the button then 2 more rows would load.

How can I limit the number of rows?

Would jQuery be the way to go?

```html
<div class="w3-content w3-container w3-padding-64" style="margin-top:50px;">
  <h3 class="w3-center w3-text-white">Never Ending Light of Day</h3>
  <br>

  <!-- Responsive Grid. Four columns on tablets, laptops and desktops. Will stack on mobile devices/small screens (100% width) -->
  <div class="w3-row-padding w3-center">
<?php
// Find all files in that folder
$files = glob('uploads/*');

// Do a natural case insensitive sort, usually 1.jpg and 10.jpg would come next to each other with a regular sort
natcasesort($files);


// Display images
foreach($files as $file) {
   echo '<div class="w3-col m3"><img src="' . $file . '" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity"/></div>';
}

?>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try `<img src="uploads/' . $file . '"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two questions here :

**How to limit the number of rows created by the php script**

You'd need to splice you `$files` array with `array_splice($files, 0, 8)`

```
<?php
// Find all files in that folder
$files = glob('uploads/*');

// Do a natural case insensitive sort, usually 1.jpg and 10.jpg would come next to each other with a regular sort
natcasesort($files);

// get only 8 files
$files = array_splice($files, 0, 8);


// Display images
foreach($files as $file) {
   echo '<div class="w3-col m3"><img src="' . $file . '" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity"/></div>';
}

?>
```

Then you can "paginate" the images list with an `$offset` variable that can be generated from request params :

```
$offset = $_GET["images_offset"] || 0; // should be a multiple of 8
$files = array_splice($files, $offset, 8);
```

**How to load new images when the user clicks the button**

jQuery could be the way to go to load asynchronously.

```
var offset = 0;
var url = "yourpageurl";
$('#yourbuttonidoranyselector').bind('click', function(){
  offset += 8;
  $.ajax(url + "?images_offset=" + offset, function(data){
    // append the new lines to the chosen container
  });
});
```

This is just a bit of the logic you should explore. Don't just copy and paste the code please.

Comment: I like this idea best, could you tell me where : $offset = $_GET["images_offset"] || 0; // should be a multiple of 8
$files = array_splice($files, $offset, 8);  would go? and where I could find resources on this logic I like it better than just loading everything and hiding all but 8.

Comment: So I 've been looking into this and haven't had any luck. I'm using this   if (isset($_GET['images_offset']))
{
 $offset = $_GET["images_offset"] || 0; // should be a multiple of 8
$files = array_splice($files, $offset, 8);
}                                                                                                              to check for the index first, no errors for php. So I think all is good. I think I might be appending the ajax incorrectly. When the button is clicked nothing happens, I made sure the buttons id and the id in the script match. Just at a lost :/

Answer (score 0):

You will display all the images first then by using jquery hide images expect first 8. Then while click show more the other 8 images will display one by one. It may work for you.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    i=7;
    $(".w3-col.m3").hide();
    $(".w3-col.m3").slice(0,7).show();
    $(".show_more").click(function(){
        i=i+8;
        $(".w3-col.m3").slice(0,i).show();
    });
});
</script>
<div class="w3-content w3-container w3-padding-64" style="margin-top:50px;">
  <h3 class="w3-center w3-text-white">Never Ending Light of Day</h3>
  <br>

  <!-- Responsive Grid. Four columns on tablets, laptops and desktops. Will stack on mobile devices/small screens (100% width) -->
  <div class="w3-row-padding w3-center">

<?php
// Find all files in that folder
$files = glob('uploads/*');

// Do a natural case insensitive sort, usually 1.jpg and 10.jpg would come next to each other with a regular sort
natcasesort($files);


// Display images
foreach($files as $file) {
   echo '<div class="w3-col m3"><img src="' . $file . '" width="20px" onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity"/></div>';
}

?>

  </div>
  <a class="show_more">Show more</a>
</div>
```